# WCF JSON Post Operation

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I need to create a Post WCF operation.  I need the user to pass in several parameters.  All of the examples I see assumes users will only ever send in one parameter.  How can I accomplish this?  Wouldn't the url the client sends be really long?

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "changeStatus/{ID}/{userID}/{activityDate}/{locationID}/{attachmentID}/{descriptionID}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void ChangeStatus(Guid ID, Guid userID, DateTime activityDate, Guid locationID, Guid attachmentID = default(Guid), Guid descriptionID = default(Guid));
```

Comment: Wrap it into a single POCO class and that should be easy enough. And since its a post operation you can just have your URL as changeStatus without any query string.

Comment: How can a user pass in a POCO class if I do not provide a parameter in the URITemplate?

Comment: Each Http Post has a message body and you can pass the POCO object via the message body.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your ChangeStatus method to receive an array of type KeyValuePair, then you could just loop through the array and get your needed values. This is typically the way I build my web services when I need to send more than one or two parameters.

If the client is doing a POST to call your service then the data can be passed as an object and not in the query string, but if it is being sent via query string then yes the url could get very long.